# Can anybody help with this state space model for filtering with random matrix connecting observation and state

Tags: bayesian, estimation, kalman-filter

I need an urgent help in an issue with a state space model for filtering. My state model is like:

$\mathbf{d}_k = \mathbf{d}_{k-1} + \boldsymbol{\eta}_k$ with $\boldsymbol{\eta}_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_\eta)$

and my observation model is like:

$y_k = \mathbf{d}_k^T \boldsymbol{\Gamma}\mathbf{z}_k + \epsilon_k$, with $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_k \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon)$.

In conventional Kalman Filter, the state vector to be estimated $\mathbf{d}_k$ is accompanied with a constant matrix like $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$. But in this case it is having an extra term $\mathbf{z}_k$ which is random with $\mathbf{z}_k = [\cos\theta_1~~ \sin\theta_1~~ \cos\theta_2~~ \cos\theta_3~~\sin\theta_3~~\cos\theta_4]^T$ is a vector with $\{\theta_1, \theta_3\}\sim^{\text{iid}} \mathcal{U}(0, 2\pi)$ and $\{\theta_2, \theta_4\}\sim^{\text{iid}} \mathcal{U}(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, $\mathcal{U}(a,b)$ denoting the uniform distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$.

I want to estimate the $\mathbf{d}_k$ only using Bayesian Principles.

Can anybody help me regarding how to proceed in this case to estimate $\mathbf{d}_k$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need software or you want an explanation regarding a suitable procedure? Also, are you familiar with the Kalman filter?

Comment: I am in need of theoretical modeling of this type. In usual Kalman Filtering we dont have the $\mathbf{z}_k$ term. Thats the problem here.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. See Wikipedia: the observation equation for Kalman problems is generally as follows: $\mathbf{z}_k = \mathbf{H}_{k} \mathbf{x}_k + \mathbf{v}_k$. So there you also have an $\mathbf{H}_k$ (depending on $k$). Loosely spoken (ignoring matrix dimensions), if you would define $\mathbf{\Gamma z_k}$ as $\mathbf{H_k}$, why wouldn't this be equivalent to your problem?

Comment: Actually problem is if I combine $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$ and $\mathbf{z}_k$ then $\boldsymbol{\Gamma}\mathbf{z}_k$ would be random as $\mathbf{z}_k$ is random. But in conventional KF, $\mathbf{H}_k$ is assumed constant if known.

Comment: I see. Might be good to make this a bit more explicit in the OP, so that it is easier for people to help you :). You could always use a Gibbs sampling approach btw, but I am not sure if that is what you want (it's not straightforward to give a derivation, but there are packages for that).

Comment: Could not understand OP???

Comment: I'm not saying the OP is not understandable. I'm saying that you should emphasize in the OP that your problem is that $z_k$ is stochastic and therefore this differs from standard KF problems.

Comment: Actually I am asking "What is OP"? Please bear with my ignorance...

Comment: OP = opening post (where you wrote your question). You can edit it by clicking the "edit" button.

Comment: Not sure this is "Bayesian" modeling, but have you tried writing out the likelihood and solving as a maximum likelihood estimation problem?  If you ignore, which may be a bad idea, that x_k doesn't have anything close to a Normal distribution, you could try to solve this via Extended Kalman Filter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter, which is very roughly speaking a nonlinear least squares model and solution. If you do this, perhaps you should reparameterize (inverse trig?) the model in terms of a transformed z_k which will be closer to being Normally distributed.